# PostgreSQL Virtual Column—column does not exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL 8.4, I'm trying to put together the following query:

```
SELECT (field_a + field_b + field_c) AS virtual_field, *
FROM "entities" 
WHERE ("entities".thing_id = 9999 AND (virtual_field > 0)) 
AND (boolean_field = 't') 
ORDER BY virtual_field DESC
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting the following error:

```
PGError: ERROR:  column "virtual_field" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ies" ("entities".thing_id = 9999 AND (virtual_fiel...
                                                 ^
```

The error message is quite obvious, but I'll be damned if I can figure out the correct syntax for what I'm trying to do. `field_a`, `field_b` and `field_c` are all real columns in my `entities` table.

For reference, I'm using Rails (2.3.11) to compose the query. Here's the (anonymised) code I'm using:

```
Thing.entities.boolean_scope.find(:all, 
  :select     => "(field_a + field_b + field_c) AS virtual_field, *",
  :conditions => ['virtual_field > ?', value],
  :order      => 'virtual_field DESC'
)
```

My brain has failed me—can anyone help me figure it out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use an alias (like `virtual_field` here) from the SELECT clause in the WHERE clause like that.

You can use them in ORDER BY but not in WHERE.

Comment: Really? Oh, damn. So, I guess I need to use `WHERE (field_a + field_b + field_c) > 0` then?

Answer (score 9):

If you put the "main" statement into a derived table, you can use the alias:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT (field_a + field_b + field_c) AS virtual_field,
               entities.*
        FROM entities 
    ) t
    WHERE thing_id = 9999 
      AND virtual_field > 0
      AND boolean_field = 't'
    ORDER BY virtual_field DESC
```

Btw: you don't need the expressioni `boolean_field = 't'` (if that is really a column of type `boolean`). `AND boolean_field` is enough as that is a valid boolean expression.